# Xcode: Error Build failed while building on iPhone

Tags: xcode, react-native, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

[image]I am trying to run my application on my iPhone and receiving the following error. It is working fine on Simulator and release builds are also getting built.

error build: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/mdjavedakhtar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/baa-ejkeyxidrdwrgyctzidcxyrfemfc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

Comment: https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/issues/1446#issuecomment-1361554645 check this one, haven't tried anything from my end yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case removing arm64 value from Excluded Architectures > Debug solved the problem. (+ it should be removed from all targets including OnesignalNotificationService)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same issue after updating macOS to 13.2 and Xcode 14.2. Deleting of the project and cloning repo with install whole the project again helped me.